# Error trying to prevent the launching of activity

Tags: android

### I am trying to launch an activity on click of a button

**LOG**

```
10-21 15:26:58.747: D/AndroidRuntime(693): Shutting down VM
10-21 15:26:58.747: W/dalvikvm(693): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial/com.project.findmybuffet.Filters}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at com.project.findmybuffet.Filters.onCreate(Filters.java:181)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-21 15:26:58.767: E/AndroidRuntime(693):  ... 11 more
10-21 15:27:42.949: I/Process(693): Sending signal. PID: 693 SIG: 9
```

**Filters.java**

```
public class Filters extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{

    // declare text objects variables
    private SeekBar PRICEbar,DISTANCEbar, RATINGbar; 
    private TextView PRICEtextProgress,DISTANCEtextProgress, RATINGtextProgress;

    Button back;
    Button FILTER;


    private RadioGroup rdg;
    private RadioButton indian;
    private RadioButton thai;
    private RadioButton chinese;


    private String selectedType="";



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.filters);   



        /** Finding all the views in this Activity. */
        PRICEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.PRICEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        DISTANCEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.DISTANCEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        RATINGbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        FILTER=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SEARCH_BUTTON_ID);

        rdg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        indian = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.IndianRG_ID);
        thai = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ThaiRG_ID);
        chinese = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.ChineseRG_ID);


        back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarFilterBackButton);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 finish();
            }
        });






        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); 
        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PRICEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PRICEtextViewProgressID);
                PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
                seekBar.setMax(100);

            }
        });







        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        DISTANCEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DISTANCEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DISTANCEtextViewProgressID);
                DISTANCEtextProgress.setText("Distance:: "+progress);
                seekBar.setMax(25);
            }
        });


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        RATINGbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RATINGtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RATINGtextViewProgressID);
                RATINGtextProgress.setText("Rating:: "+progress);
                seekBar.setMax(5); 

                RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGfinalvalueratingID);
                ratingBar.setRating(5);
                ratingBar.setFocusable(false);

                RatingBar ratingBar1 = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.RATINGinitialvalueratingID);
                ratingBar1.setRating(0);
                ratingBar.setFocusable(false);
            }
        });


        rdg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                if(i==R.id.BreakfastRG_ID){
                    selectedType = indian.getText().toString();
                }else if(i==R.id.LunchRG_ID){
                    selectedType = thai.getText().toString();
                }else{
                    selectedType = chinese.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });

        FILTER.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent FilterIntent=new Intent(Filters.this,AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);
                FilterIntent.putExtra("REST1",selectedType);
                FilterIntent.putExtra("PriceBar", PRICEbar.getProgress());
                FilterIntent.putExtra("DistanceBar", DISTANCEbar.getProgress());
                FilterIntent.putExtra("RatingBar", RATINGbar.getProgress());

                startActivity(FilterIntent);
            }
        });






    }
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (seekBar == PRICEbar)
            PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
        else if (seekBar == DISTANCEbar)
            DISTANCEtextProgress.setText("Distance:: "+progress);
        else if (seekBar == RATINGbar)
            RATINGtextProgress.setText("Rating:: "+progress);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

I am getting error after i place this code

```
FILTER.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent FilterIntent=new Intent(Filters.this,AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.class);
                FilterIntent.putExtra("REST1",selectedType);
                FilterIntent.putExtra("PriceBar", PRICEbar.getProgress());
                FilterIntent.putExtra("DistanceBar", DISTANCEbar.getProgress());
                FilterIntent.putExtra("RatingBar", RATINGbar.getProgress());

                startActivity(FilterIntent);
            }
        });
```

That code is used to launch a new activity so it is essential

Where should i place that code in `filter.java`

- When i click the button to launch a activity, i get `null pointer
  exception`
- As i am not passing any value from one activity to another
- How to resolve this

Comment: The stack trace says it all, you have a NullPointerException being thrown at line 181. Whatever is on that line is null.

Comment: FILTER.setOnClickListener ...... is at that line ....

Comment: @smriti3 Please check whether you have SEARCH_BUTTON_ID button within filters layout

Comment: Is FILTER null?, if not then its something in the click listener, either PRICEbar, DISTANCEbar, RATINGbar. There is also the possibility something in your AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView Activity's onCreate method is causing the issue

Comment: @ SathishKumar ......... yes that was the mistake .... i mentioned the wrond id .... thanks i resolved it

Comment: @ triggs ....... error was caused due to referencing wrong ID for the Button from XML .... i resolved it .....

Comment: @ Stealz .... error was caused due to referencing wrong ID for the Button from XML .... i resolved it ..... its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mention this class `AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView.java` into manifest file.

Comment: I mentioned it ...... but that is not the cause of error here .... ... i dont know where to place FILTER.setOnClickListener in the filter.java..... that block is causing the error

Answer (score 1):

I had mentioned the wrong ID while referencing from the layout ......

Instead of

```
FILTER=(Button) findViewById(R.id.TopNavigationBarFilterDoneButton);
```

i used

```
FILTER=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SEARCH_BUTTON_ID);
```

SathishKumar hint helped me resolve it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not declared the `AndroidTabRestaurantDescSearchListView` Activity in Manifset.And also check your `FILTER` view ID